# Is there a module like Rails Devise in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Up until now I have mainly worked on Ruby On Rails.

I recently studied Node.js and felt that NPM in Node.js is very different from Gem in Rails.

Rails' libraries provide the best environment. Like Devise Gem.

However, I think that a lot of proficiency is needed to implement functions like Devise using Node.js.

I am a beginner and this is having a hard time creating a web application with Node.js.

How can I get out of Rails and learn only Node.js?

And how can you find and use efficient NPMs?

Comment: Huh - what does Devise do?  There might be an equivalent in Node/NPM or other package manager.  But folks who are not familiar with Devise cannot answer without looking it up on their own.  Help us help you :)

Comment: Take a look at a http://www.passportjs.org/

Comment: My English skills were so poor that I could not communicate my opinion correctly.

For example, I have not been thinking about User Session while developing through Rails. Devise gem gave us everything.

Of course, I know this is not a good method. However, even if you do not have a good understanding of cookies and sessions, I think it's tempting to implement functionality through the library.

I did the following to build a User Session through Node.js: 1. MongoDB modeling 2. User authentication using Passport.

Comment: This process is not easy for beginners. Is Node.js easy to develop with just the environment provided by the library?

The NPM I've used has provided a basic API, and I feel that the rest is up to you.

Comment: @ ykit9 Thanks buddy.

I have completed the functions I want using passport :)

Is there anything easy for beginners like Rails Gem to use? I wrote this because I thought it was.

I think this is the advantages and disadvantages of Express. I know there is a Framework called Sails, but I do not seem to be as good at Node.js as Rails.

It's too sad ...